# Filtering out different narrow-band frequencies at once

Tags: filter-design, python, fourier, scipy

I have asked a closely related question on SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168460/python-implementation-for-filtering-out-multiple-distinct-narrow-band-frequencie

but I am still unclear if my problem is an implementation issue or more theoretical.

I have the following signal and its power spectrum:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the most important periodicities using Python: 24 hr, 12 hr, 8 hr, 6 hr and 4 hr. The signal is sampled every 6 min over 15 days. Ultimately I'll need to do this on other durations, these are just subsets of the data i'm working on.

The `scipy.signal` provides various tools for filtering and it's difficult to see what's the most appropriate for this kind of data: I need to minimize ringing, so a sharp cut at the peak frequencies is not preferred, i.e., I do not just want to do something like (e.g to eliminate a 6 hr periodicity):

```
from scipy import fftpack

time_step = 6*60 
peak_freq = 1 / 6 / 3600
sig_fft = fftpack.fft(sig)
sample_freq = fftpack.fftfreq(sig.size, d=time_step)
sig_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) > peak_freq] = 0
filtered_sig = np.real(fftpack.ifft(sig_fft))
```

Instead, I read it would better to use `scipy.signal.filtfilt` in combination with a choice of function that create smoother filters like `scipy.signal.iirnotch`:

```
fs = 1/time_step
Q = 30.0
b, a = iirnotch(peak_freq, Q, fs=fs)
filtered_data = filtfilt(b, a, data)
```

However, this way of building the filter does not give a transfer function that I can multiply for different peak frequencies that i'd like to get rid of. In theory once we have different transfer function, e.g. H1(w), H2(w), ... Hn(w) where Hi(w), i=1,...N filtering peak frequencies f1, f2, ... fN, then the transfer function to filter out all of them would be H(w) = H1(w) * H2(w) *... *Hn(w) and there would be only one FFT and inverse FFT needed.

What Python functions can give me that semantics?

Comment: why are you `filtfilt`ering? and: you're right, a compound filter is just the individual filter coefficients convolved. and: I don't exactly see where in your last paragraph an FFT/IFFT comes into play – the whole point was that you didn't want to use an FFT-based nulling (which I agree is probably a good idea).

Comment: By the way, since these are IIRs, this is a relatively interesting question; still: I'm wondering to what end you want to do all this filtering – what's the thing you want to do with the signal afterwards?

Comment: On your question about FFT / IFFT, I had assumed filtfilt was working in the Fourier domain as iirnotch gives coefficient to build a transfer function in the frequency domain. Doesn't filtfilt work in the Fourier domain then? 
The data are from the NASA SDO mission (public data), I need to filter that out to remove spacecraft-related systematics. The periodicities are due to some orbital effects.

Comment: no, `filtfilt` doesn't work in frequency domain. And `iirnotch` doesn't give coefficients to build something in frequency domain. Read these two function's documentation!

Comment: That was actually an assumption based on the few details given by the documentation of `filtfilt`, described as zero-phase filtering method which is what I needed, more than `lfilter`. The latter was more documented and described things with a transfer function with a z variable, assumed to be the typical complex variable in the absence of more explaination. I don't want to specifically use `filtfilt`. I can design the fourier-domain filters by hand with a set of different filters, i just know it will be slower than something that already exists.

Comment: Also for completeness, the only technical [reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=492552) of `filtfilt` says it is extending work implemented with FFTs.

Comment: that is the reference that discusses the initial state problem of `filtfilt`; the documentation of `filtfilt` is pretty clear: "This function applies a linear filter twice, once forward and once backwards." The fact that under the hood it's implemented using fast convolution using FFTs doesn't change the operation done!

Comment: Correct. I had no idea what representation the code is actually using. We can define a filter in either the temporal domain or frequency domain for easier representation, doesn't say what the code actually uses (lfilter mention both). The Fourier domain is just easier for me to understand, and the one I want for efficiency reasons.

Comment: hm, I'm really intrigued how you'd *define* an IIR in frequency domain in a discrete system?

Comment: I do not want to design IIR filters specifically. I'm asking for Python function that gives me the Fourier semantics of building filters in the frequency domain that I can multiply between each other so I only have to perform one FFT and one inverse FFT. 'filtfilt', 'iirnotch' was just things I came across, not what I want to actually use.

Comment: Ok, so the question is "how to design IIRs in frequency domain in order to multiply them to get the composite effect?", gotcha. Hm. Not sure that is possible at all – since IIR implies the time domain is infinite, and for usefulness not periodic, it means that the frequency domain representation is also neither discrete nor finite – and hence, you simply *can't* find an adequate representation that allows your multiplication to be equivalent to convolving these filters in time domain. But I might be a little confused, here.

Comment: Something like that yes, although I don't think I need my filters to comply with the characteristics  of IIRs. The fact that my example used such filters was not intentional. I'd like to do my FFT then build those composed filter that minimizes ringing (Butterworth or whatever), then IFFT, done. I'm gonna do them from scratch now, using the equivalent that I did in 2D for images, and posting that as an update and maybe someone will point to something equivalent that's part of an existing package. I just didn't want to reinvent something that could already be existing.

Comment: why not simply design your FIRs, then convolve them, get one composite filter, done?

Comment: I'm just more experienced with working in the fourier domain, I never worked with FIRs for this kind of filtering for efficiency reasons. FFT has been highly efficient when working on time series for each individual pixel of a 16 MP detector, I had no incentives to work with FIRs before, as used in examples of the `scipy.signal` package. The duration of the data is several years of uninterrupted observations at a 45s cadence. If you have a better reason for me to use such FIRs instead, then I'll look into it as well.

Comment: If you're doing filtering simply by multiplication after a FFT, then you're doing cyclic convolution with the equivalent (i.e. IFFT of the vector you point-wise multiply with) in the time domain. That's not really filtering! Filtering is non-cyclic convolution. From the detector description: is it possible that your data is cyclic in nature from the beginning, or are you perhaps multiplying with a vector the same size as your overall observation (in which the performance gain over time-domain convolution is probably zero)?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting at by "not really filtering". Getting rid of specific frequencies is filtering, whether you do it in time or frequency domain. A butterworth filter does that, it's filtering. "not really filtering" is maybe your personal point of view due to the field you work in, but this does not help the purpose of this question.
As I explained the periodicties are due to orbital effects. Like going around Earth every 24 hours due to the orbit. Thermal day/night differences (12 hours), etc...

Comment: The periodicity needs to be an integer factor of your FFT length if you don't want improper edge effects.

Comment: Yes, that's a good reminder. You think I could use padding for that? 
I just came across the implementation that I had in mind there: http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/425/Lab5/index.html 
They use notch filters in the frequency domain and simply multiply them. It's done for images, I'll try to adapt that to the 1D time-frequency case of my problem.